# Label inside UpdatePanel will not show value assigned from code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm at my wits end here. I've defined a user control for a modal that lets users change a password. Inside the modal, the fields are contained in an UpdatePanel, and I'd like to display a success/error message regarding the result of the password change request. However, the Label controls simply will not change.

Markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reqValidator1;
    var reqValidator2;
    var regValidator;
    var compValidator;

    function configPasswordValidators() {
        reqValidator1 = $("#<%= RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID %> ")[0];
        reqValidator2 = $("#<%= RequiredFieldValidator2.ClientID %> ")[0];
        regValidator = $("#<%= RegularExpressionValidator1.ClientID %> ")[0];
        compValidator = $("#<%= CompareValidator1.ClientID %> ")[0];
    }

    function enablePasswordValidators() {
        ValidatorEnable(reqValidator1, true);
        ValidatorEnable(reqValidator2, true);
        ValidatorEnable(regValidator, true);
        ValidatorEnable(compValidator, true);
    }

    function disablePasswordValidators() {
        ValidatorEnable(reqValidator1, false);
        ValidatorEnable(reqValidator2, false);
        ValidatorEnable(regValidator, false);
        ValidatorEnable(compValidator, false);
    }

    function showProcessingSpinner() {
        $("#dvChangeUserPasswordBtns").hide();
        $("#dvProcessing").show();
        $("#<%= btnChange.ClientID %>").click();
    }
</script>
<div class="new-container new-modal" id="newContainerPanel">
    <div runat="server" id="credentialManagerModal" class="new-container-inner panel panel-default" style="width: 600px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlChangePassword" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-right" style="width: 160px; padding-top: 15px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword1" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-left: -20px; margin-right: -20px; padding-top: 8px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="100" Width="260px" CssClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="password" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword1" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="false" Style="margin-left: 40px; color: red;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-right" style="width: 160px; padding-top: 7px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword2" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-left: -20px; margin-right: -20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="100" Width="260px" CssClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 7px;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="password" ControlToValidate="txtPassword2" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="false" Style="margin-left: 40px; color: red;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationGroup="password" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword1" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="false" Style="margin-left: 30px; color: red;"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword2" Operator="Equal" Type="String" ValidationGroup="password" ControlToCompare="txtPassword1" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" Enabled="false" Style="margin-left: 20px; color: red;"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChangePasswordSuccess" ForeColor="MediumSeaGreen"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChangePasswordError" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="passwordModalFooter" class="modal-footer">
                    <div id="dvChangeUserPasswordBtns" class="text-center">
                        <button id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default" onclick="HideChangePasswordModal();" style="float: left;">Cancel</button>
                        <button id="btnProcessChange" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showProcessingSpinner();" style="float: right;">Change Password</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center" id="dvProcessing" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="../Images/progress-spinner.gif" />&nbsp;Processing... 
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" CssStyle="btn btn-primary change-password-button" OnClick="ChangePassword_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string retVal = ChangePassword(Request.QueryString["ID"]); // Separate processing method that is working fine.

    if (retVal == "Password changed.")
    {
        lblChangePasswordSuccess.Text = retVal;
        lblChangePasswordError.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        lblChangePasswordSuccess.Text = string.Empty;
        lblChangePasswordError.Text = retVal;
    }
}
```

ScriptManager in the master page looks like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" EnablePartialRendering="True" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
```

What I've tried:

- Changing around the `UpdatePanel` attributes. Doesn't matter if I use `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` or define the triggers manually. Doesn't matter if I use "Always" or "Conditional" for the `UpdateMode`.
- Calling `UpdatePanel1.Update()` from the code behind has no effect.
- Trying to edit the label (or any other element type I put in its place) via a javascript call doesn't work either. Something like `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upnlChangePassword, this.GetType(), "script", string.Format("DisplayProcessingMessage('{0}');", retVal), true);` has no effect.

I've stepped through the code over and over—all events are firing correctly and the correct values are being returned. I've inspected the DOM before and after the partial postback and the element is always unchanged. There are no javascript errors detected in the browser.

This sits in a user control inside a web form that utilizes a master page. In the browser, there is far more in the page than would be useful to post here, so I recognize there could be something outside this file in play. But if I could at least have an idea of what to look for that could cause this behavior, it would be an enormous help.

Comment: Does it work well if you don't use the UpdatePanel?

Comment: All ASP.NET controls must be inside the main form to work correctly. Sometimes modals append themselves to the bottom of the page, just before the closing </body> tag. Which modal control are you using?

Comment: @ConnorsFan: Interestingly, no. I'm not sure what that signifies. Firing a full postback means that some javascript in the parent page is getting called, but I can't think of or see anything that would prevent a simple Label.Text property from being set.

Comment: And the value of these Labels is not modified in `Page_Load`, by any chance?

Comment: @Mahesh: I'm using Bootstrap's modal markup. The user control I've placed it in is definitely inside the <form> element.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: Nope, the `Page_Load` contents of the user control and the parent are both wrapped in `if (!IsPostBack)` clauses.

Comment: You can try adding a dummy Label, maybe above the `newContainerPanel` div, and see if you can set its Text successfully. If that works, you could move it next to the ones that you actually use and see if it still works. That would tell you if the problem is global or specific to your two Labels.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `PostBackTrigger` to your update panel:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnChange" />
</Triggers>
```

**OR**

As a work around, instead of calling a server side click event you could use an AJAX call which posts to a C# `[WebMethod]`.

**1.Replace your `showProcessingSpinner()` function with this:**

```
function showProcessingSpinner() {

    $("#dvChangeUserPasswordBtns").hide();
    $("#dvProcessing").show();
    //$("#<%= btnChange.ClientID %>").click();

    var id = getQueryStringParamByName("ID");
    alert("Query string parameter value for ID is - " + id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ModalPopupAndUpdatePanel.aspx/ChangePasswordWeb",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id:"' + id + '"}',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert('Success Message - ' + data.d.SuccessMessage);
            var successMessage = data.d.SuccessMessage;
            $("#lblChangePasswordSuccess").text(successMessage);
        },
        error: function (errordata) {
            alert('Error.AJAX call failed')
        }
    });
}


function getQueryStringParamByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**2.Create a web method in the code behind called *ChangePasswordWeb*:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static AJAXResponse ChangePasswordWeb(string id)
{
    string retVal = ChangePassword(id);
    var response = new AJAXResponse();

    if (retVal == "Password changed.")
        response.SuccessMessage = retVal;
    else
        response.ErrorMessage = retVal;

    return response;
}
```

**3. In the HTML** - had to remove the `OnClick` event from `btnChange` and change the `ScriptManager` control to look like this - `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server" EnableCdn="true" />`

**Output:**

[image: Calling a WebMethod from jQuery using AJAX]