# How to show message from code behind in bootstrap's modal popup in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3, postback, bootstrap-modal

Actually what I mean is when I click the asp dot net button which is located in the modal popup.
when I click that button I want to print the message from the server that data is properly saved or not.

When I click the button bootstrap's modal pop up is vanished bcoz of the postback.
what can i do to print the mesage from server.

**Below is my modal pop uo code in HTML.**

```
<!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

 <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**c# Code**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "I am called";
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to print the message in the popup or anywhere on the page?

Comment: I want the message in the popup itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add logic to the click event to re-open the modal after the post back OR look for an alternative method of posting back to the server such as using AJAX.

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "I am called";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal();", true);
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showModal() {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
                showModal();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show Modal" />
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: How we can achieve the same using the AJAX can you please show me

Comment: If you want to do it via AJAX, remove the OnClick event from the button.Add a [WebMethod] to your code behind and call that webmethod using $.ajax.Here's an example -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340653/label-inside-updatepanel-will-not-show-value-assigned-from-code-behind/38342971#38342971